# My load more button is not showing despite everything being correct according to me

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

HTML side code

```
<template name="profPageAuthorSubmit">
    <div>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="pclProf">
            <li><img id="profilePagePic" src="{{profilePagePicture}}"><span class="username">{{authorSubmit}}</span></li>
            <li class="accesories">{{a}} Poems</li>
            <li class="accesories">{{b}} Short stories</li>
            <li class="accesories">{{c}} Followers</li>
            <li class="accesories">{{d}} Followings</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="pcl">
    {{#each Contents}}
      <li class="p">
        <p class="bucket">  
          <li><span class="contentType">{{type}}</span></li>
          <li><span class="titleBody"><strong>{{{title}}}</strong></span></li>
          <li><a href="/user/{{createdBy}}"><img class="authorPic" src="{{authorPhoto}}"><span class="authorName">{{author}}</span></a></li>
          <li><span class="createdAtTime">Written at {{createdAt}}</span></li>  
          <li class="contentMain">{{{content}}}</li>
          {{>contentEssentials}}
          {{#if editing}}
            {{>contentEdit}}
          {{/if}}
          {{>commentsTemp}}
        </p>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    **{{#if nextPath}}
        <a href="{{nextPath}}" class="btn btn-default load-more">Load more</a>
          {{#unless ready}}
            {{> spinner}}
          {{/unless}}
    {{/if}}**
    </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Client side code

```
profileController= RouteController.extend({
  template: 'profPageAuthorSubmit',
  increment: 10,
  contentsLimit: function() {
    return parseInt(this.params.contentsLimit) || this.increment;
  },
  findOptions: function() {
    return {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: this.contentsLimit()};
  },
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.ContentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('contents', this.findOptions());
    return Meteor.subscribe('allUserData');
  },
  Contents: function() {
    var locationArray= location.href.split('/');
    var UserId= locationArray[4];
    return contentsList.find({createdBy: UserId, anonymous: false}, this.findOptions());
  },
  data: function() {
    var hasMore = this.Contents().count() === this.contentsLimit();
    var nextPath = this.route.path({contentsLimit: this.contentsLimit() + this.increment});
    console.log("ready");
    return {
      Contents: this.Contents(),
      ready: this.ContentsSub.ready,
      nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
    };
}
});

Router.map(function(){
  Router.route('profPageAuthorSubmit',{
    path: '/user/:createdBy/:contentsLimit?',
    controller: profileController
  });
});
```

Why is load-more button not showing. I have checked it again and again but still it is not showing. The same thing has worked in other templates.
Basically it is checking whether the contents number is greater than the number displayed, if it is then the load more button should show.
Thanking all

Comment: Try wrapping hasNext into a function so it can be reactive, like so:
`nextPath: function(){ return hasMore ? nextPath : null};`

Comment: @Sindis  It did not work. Any idea as to why it is happening?

Comment: My guess is that `hasMore` is always returning false for some reason. Set a breakpoint on your `data:` function in the inspector and see what's actually going on there.

Comment: @MichelFloyd "hasmore" is returning true only if the number of items is more than the required number. The worst part is the same code is working in other templates but not this one

Comment: Not sure how that can be, `hasMore` is looking for `===` and not `>=`

Comment: I could not find the solution till now but one question where is it getting stuck? Any better way in which it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, every child of a "ul" tag must be a "li" tag. So the "a" isnt recognized. Try to put the content inside a "li" tag.

Comment: I placed that inside an "li" tag. But it still did not show. Any other suggestions would be hugely appreciated.